# How do we implement a curl post in pharo

Tags: curl, smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

I have curl post to implement in pharo, but it seems like there is not much in term of explanation on how to do that. 
I saw few example but they ARE way simpler than what I need to. 
I would you do that inn pharos?

```
$ curl 'https://url_server' \
-X POST \
-H 'key: MY PASSWORD' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d \
'{
  "HEADER": "FOO",
  "DESK": "POO",
  "FORWARDTO": "another_url"
}'
```

I know that this is similar to post using Znclient like so:

```
 ZnClient new
    url: 'url_server';
    entity: (ZnEntity 
            with:'{"HEADER": "FOO", 
                   "DESK": "POO",
                   "FORWARDTO": "another_url"}'
            type: ZnMimeType applicationJson
            );
        post.
```

However where does the key goes to using this syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for the way to set a **HTTP header field** for your request in Zinc?

Try `ZnClient`:

```
headerAt: key put: value
    "Set key equals value in the HTTP header of the current request"
```

Your code then could look like:

```smalltalk
ZnClient new
    url: 'yourURL';
    headerAt: 'headerKey' put: 'headerValue'; 
    entity: (ZnEntity 
        with:'{"yourJSON": "Content"}'
        type: ZnMimeType applicationJson);
    post.
```

Zinc also has a nice feature, that shows you a curl command line invocation equivalent to the current request. So you can compare to the curl line you had in mind. Just print:

```smalltalk
ZnClient new
    url: 'yourURL';
    headerAt: 'headerKey' put: 'headerValue'; 
    entity: (ZnEntity 
        with:'{"yourJSON": "Content"}'
        type: ZnMimeType applicationJson);
    method: #POST;
    curl.
```

You'll find a [good documentation for using Zinc HTTP as client](https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/EnterprisePharoBook/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/Zinc-HTTP-Client/Zinc-HTTP-Client.html) in the [Enterprise Pharo book](http://books.pharo.org/enterprise-pharo/).

Comment: Thanks @MartinW. But I am using ZnClient here. Is my syntax wrong? should I add the key value as I did for the url?

Comment: *Zinc* is the name of the framework `ZnClient` belongs to. Hence the *Zn* Prefix for *Zinc* :)

Comment: I extended the answer using your example.

Comment: Thanks @MartinW This seems more like what I needed. So the key should be in the headerAt

Comment: Dear @MartinW , Just one last question. How can I check the Json response given by the server after the post done,?

Comment: @ludo Just check the answer. From the comment of `ZnClinent>>post`: _Execute a HTTP POST on the request set up **and return the response #contents**_